# AWS Event Driven Batch w/ Asynchronous Inputs That must be paired

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I have data coming into two DynamoDB tables. Let's call them Widgets and Kerfuffles. Each Widget "has a" Kerfuffle, but a Kerfuffle could belong to several Widgets. Now normally, I'd say I could use DDB Streams to kick off a lambda to publish my Widget-Kerfuffle pair to SNS. However, Widgets and their Kerfuffles don't necessarily arrive together. In fact, the Kerfuffle could arrive 5-10 minutes before or after the Widget.

So it would seem like I can't just have a lambda trigger on the Widget or the Kerfuffle being Created because the other half might not be present (and I don't want to send down duplicate Widgets either).

Any suggestions on how to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typing is hard. Let widget = `A` and kerfuffle = `B`.

1. Real-time: you process notifications off of new `A`'s **and** new `B`'s. For each `A` notification, you check whether `B` is present. If it isn't stop. Else, process that `A`. For each `B` notification, you *collect all present `A`'s matching it*, and process them all. Note that you'll need some sort of locking here if you want to avoid processing `A`'s multiple times if they trigger very close to their `B` and both processes succeed.
2. Near-real-time: once in a while (every `t` minutes), find all `A`'s that have not been processed. Process all those that have matching `B`'s, and mark those `A`'s as processed.

#### Tradeoffs:

Method 1:

- You process a bunch of notifications that don't actually matter, because you can't act on `A`'s that don't have `B`'s yet.
- You add the complexity of processing two separate streams which can interfere with one-another, unless you keep your processing single-threaded.

Method 2:

- You delay processing by `t` minutes. This can be inconsequential or **extremely impractical**, depending on your application.

Comment: Given that Bs can be duplicated (which I failed to mention) does 1 still work? An A and its B arrive and are exported. Then a second copy of that B arrives, we would export that first A a second time.

Comment: It sounds like 2 might be the best option given that a small delay is unimportant.

Comment: You can de-dup notifications in general, which might well be a wise idea if duplicates are a problem: both SNS and (non-fifo) SQS guarantee at-least-once delivery, but can and do send duplicates. The alternative, if your processing is small and over-writing is OK, is to just process duplicates, but this is an application-specific choice.